# How to fetch all fields of parent document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregation

I have tried to fetch all fields of parent document using **$group** but it send only specific fields.
**Another Question. How to fetch all fields of parent document using '$project'?**

Collection "**Opportunity**" 
Document #1

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c42b737cd94891a57fbf33e"),
    "accountId" : [
         ObjectId("5c29f198b248d845931a1830"),
         ObjectId("5c29f198b248d845931a1831"),
    ]
    "name" : "OppNewTest01",
    "value" : 10000,
    "status" : "open",
}
```

Collection "**Account**"
Document #1

```
{        
     "_id" : ObjectId("5c29f198b248d845931a1830"),
     "name" : "MyTestAcc",
     "phone" : "7845124578",
}
```

My MongoDB Query,

```
con.collection('opportunity').aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "account"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'account',
            localField: 'accountId',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'accounts',
        },
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$accounts'
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "account": { "$push": "$accounts" }
        }
    },
    ]).toArray((err, res) => {
        cbFun(res, err);
});
```

**Output** of the above query,

```
{
    "_id" : "5c42b737cd94891a57fbf33e",
    "account": [
         {        
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c29f198b248d845931a1830"),
            "name" : "MyTestAcc",
            "phone" : "7845124578",
         },
         {        
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c29f198b248d845931a1831"),
            "name" : "MyTestAcc1",
            "phone" : "7845124579",
         },
    ]
}
```

I want to below output,

```
{
    "_id" : "5c42b737cd94891a57fbf33e",
    "accountId" : [
           ObjectId("5c29f198b248d845931a1830"),
           ObjectId("5c29f198b248d845931a1831"),
    ],
    "name" : "OppNewTest01",
    "value" : 10000,
    "status" : "open",
    "account": [
         {        
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c29f198b248d845931a1830"),
            "name" : "MyTestAcc",
            "phone" : "7845124578",
         },
         {        
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c29f198b248d845931a1831"),
            "name" : "MyTestAcc1",
            "phone" : "7845124579",
         },
    ]
}
```

I have tried to fetch above output but not getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just losing that data when you $group, save those fields in that stage to keep them.

```
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "account": { "$push": "$accounts" },
            value: {$first: "$value"},
            status: {$first: "$status},
            name: {$first: "$name"},
            accountId: {$push: "$accountId},
        }
    }

EDIT:
[
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "accounts": { "$push": "$accounts" },
            "doc": {$first: "$$ROOT"},
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
              "doc.accounts" :"$accounts"
        }
     }
]
```

Comment: Without writing     value: {$first: "$value"}. If i have 15 fields, then we need to write 15 fields. so that, share other option if available.

Comment: No, you need the $first. if you have so many fields you want in theory you can push the entire document  however that is really messy and will give you redundancies

Comment: How to push entire document?

Comment: add doc: {$first: "$$ROOT"} to your group stage.

Comment: Above Comment is working But i am getting... { root_document_fields, "accounts" : { "name" : "MyTestAcc" } } .....I want accounts objects in array.

Comment: i edited my answer to fit you, you can do a lot of structure "games" with addfields and project to get any result you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192632/discussion-between-manoj-ghediya-and-tom-slabbaert).